# Bulk import of Web service vs. import scenario

Tags: acumatica

I've recently come across some code from Github for using a multi-threaded Inventory Item import using web services:

https://github.com/Acumatica/InventoryItemImportMultiThreaded

I'd like to know if this is faster or better than using an import scenario for mass import, and what may be the advantages of one over the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have used the multi-threaded inventory import and it is MUCH faster than an import Scenario.  We were importing 250K Stock Items.  Doing via import scenario, which only uses one thread, took 26 hours.  Using the tool on Github brought that down to 6 hours.  Be aware though that Acumatica limits your processing power to the licensed amount of cores.  The license we used was an enterprise license so we could use a lot of cores. Here is a great article that talks about bulk loading: [Optomizing Large Import](http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/12/optimizing-large-import.html)